# Search for questions without comments

Tags: support, search

How do I search for questions without comments? I'd like to get a solid list of ok/good questions that aren't answered yet, and see how I can help there.

I'm using:

```
[tag] score:1 answers:0 closed:false
```

But this list includes questions that are already 'answered' in the comments. The [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) doesn't mention searching for comments.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post an answer on any questions you find that are only 'answered' in the comments. Just cite the original commenter and summarize the answer, adding any other relevant information you can think of.

Comment: Always feels a bit dirty to do that as if I'm 'stealing' someone's rep...

Comment: @Sobrique They apparently didn't want it. It's only fake internet points, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this [sede query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266777/questions-without-comments)

```
select top 1000
       p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
left outer join comments c on c.postid = p.id
inner join posttags pt on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Questions
and c.id is null -- no comments
and t.tagname ='##tag##'  -- tag
and answercount =0   -- no answers
and p.score > 0  -- score 1 or greater
and closeddate is null -- not closed
```

Remember that the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) is only updated once a week (in the weekend) so you won't find the newest questions in there.