# How to filter questions without comments?

Tags: support, search

I want to contribute some answers in some questions. But when I try to filter out like unanswered & get into some questions I always find that answers is already discussed in the comment section. Ok, That's good. But how can I filter questions that do not have comments yet?

My question may be duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284152/search-for-questions-without-comments), I'm reposting as there is no latest answers there and I have read [the search model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but couldn't find "without comments" feature. If that feature isn't available, Stack Overflow staff should look into this.

Comment: If you don't care about it being recent (the data is up to 7 days old, which means it will result in some questions that have since received comments), [you can use SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com). Even if this was planned, it'd still take a long time before it'd get implemented, making SEDE much faster

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1411687  (keep in mind SEDE is updated on Sunday so the data might be stale)

Comment: If you are looking for questions with no *answers*, you can use a search term like `is:question closed:no answers:0`. If you really mean *comments* then please note the [narrow purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) comments have. SO is a questions & answers site, comments play no great role.

Comment: There's a userscript that adds [comment indicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGmw.png) under posts in the search view, which could help you parse out comment-less posts while searching. It's called [Fetch Question Stats](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#fetch-question-stats); it's one script from a set that's collectively curated/ created by [@SamuelLiew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew), called "[Stack Overflow Moderation Userscripts](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#stack-overflow-moderation-userscripts)", if you fancy taking a look.

Comment: Just because a question does not have recent answers does not mean you get to ask it again. The question does not have more recent answers because that feature has not been added.

Comment: As someone who reviews a lot of questions each week I don't see any value in this filter. Lots of comments are incorrect, or promote bad practices or don't solve the actual problem. The existence of comments wouldn't tell me anything of importance without reading the question and any comments (if applicable). It usually doesn't take much time

Answer (score 2):

Comments are irrelevant in the face of questions and answers.  [Jeanne Dark's search string](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407808/how-to-filter-questions-without-comments#comment844185_407808) will get you exactly what you're looking for.

```
is:question closed:no answers:0
```